# Why is my legend not appearing next to the graph?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, scatter-plot

I have two different datasets in one scatter plot, prediction2020_bounds needs to be blue in the legend and median2020 needs to be red in the legend.
Here my code:

```
  ggplot() + 
      
    # Points without corona
    geom_line(data=prediction2020_bounds, aes(x = Date, y = lwr), colour = "blue", linetype = "solid") +
    geom_line(data=prediction2020_bounds, aes(x = Date, y = upr), colour = "blue", linetype = "solid") +
    geom_ribbon(data=prediction2020_bounds, aes(x = Date, ymin = lwr, ymax = upr), alpha=.4) +
    labs(x = "Date", y = "Median Daily Price", title = "Daily Median Price", colour = "Legend Title\n") +
    scale_x_date(date_breaks="1 month", date_labels="%Y %m") +
    scale_colour_manual(labels = c("prediction2020_bounds", "median2020"), values = c(prediction2020_bounds, median2020)) +
    theme_bw() +
    geom_point(data=prediction2020_bounds, aes(x=Date, y=Price),fill="blue",
          colour="darkblue", size=1) +
    
    
    #Points with corona 2020 year
    geom_point(data=median2020, aes(x=Date, y=Price), fill="red",
            colour="red", size=1)
```

Comment: It's because you don't assign colours in the `aes()` portion of a layer. If you do `aes(..., colour = "my legend item")`, it will map the colours to a scale, which will generate a legend.

Answer (score 0):

Next time please consider include some reproducible example so it would be easier for other to support you in finding a good answer ;)

For legend to be displayed in `ggplot2` you need to map the `colour` or `fill` inside the `mapping` param with `aes()` instead of what you are doing in the questions. The code below is a way to achieve what you want to do.

I also re-format the code a bit in my personal preference where the configuration of the plot `scales`, `labels`, `theme` are all at the bottom while the `geom` is at the top of `ggplot` command. This is just personal preference.

Hope this help you get better understanding of the legend in `ggplot2`.

```
color_names <- c("prediction 2020 bounds", "median 2020")
color_values <- c("blue", "red")
names(color_values) <- color_names
ggplot() + 
  
  # Points without corona
  geom_line(data=prediction2020_bounds, aes(x = Date, y = lwr,
    # assign the colour to the same name as blue value of color_values
    colour = "prediction 2020 bounds"),  linetype = "solid") +
  geom_line(data=prediction2020_bounds, aes(x = Date, y = upr,
    # assign the colour to the same name as blue value of color_values
    colour = "prediction 2020 bounds"), linetype = "solid") +
  geom_ribbon(data=prediction2020_bounds, aes(x = Date, ymin = lwr, ymax = upr),
    alpha=.4) +
  geom_point(data=prediction2020_bounds, aes(x=Date, y=Price,
    # assign the fill to the same name as blue value of color_values
    fill="prediction 2020 bounds"), 
    colour="darkblue", size=1) +

  #Points with corona 2020 year
  geom_point(data=median2020, aes(x=Date, y=Price, 
    # assign the colour to the same name as red value of color_values
    fill="median 2020"),
    colour="median 2020", size=1) +
  
  # plot configuration scales, theme, etc...
  labs(x = "Date", y = "Median Daily Price",
    title = "Daily Median Price", colour = "Legend Title\n") +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks="1 month", date_labels="%Y %m") +
  scale_colour_manual(values = color_values) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = color_values) +
  theme_bw()
```

In addition to that you can use `theme(legend.position = [position]` where
`[position]` can be

- `none`: for no legend display
- `left/right/botom/top`: corresponded position relate to the main plot area

I found this article is very informative with thorough explaination
https://aosmith.rbind.io/2018/07/19/manual-legends-ggplot2/

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it's very close to what I want to have. However, the dots in the legend are both red instead of blue and red.

Comment: It really hard to do it without a reproducible example to ensure that we are running on the samething. If you can provide a minimal reproducible example as the link below it would be a lot easier for other to support you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: yes thank you for your comment, I will share a new question with a reproducible example.

Comment: Please check my new question, this question is broken down to the problem I have